# Why is Android GPS location returning disabled despite having turned it on

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, location

I am working on a project that uses GPS. I've requested the user for the Location permissions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Next, I check if GPS is enabled using this code;

```
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (lm != null) {

        //Check if GPS is Enabled
        boolean isGPSEnabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (!isGPSEnabled) {
            //Open settings page                        
            startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));

        }else {
            locationMap = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if (locationMap != null) {
                longitude = locationMap.getLongitude();
                latitude = locationMap.getLatitude();
            }
        }
    }
```

If GPS is not enabled, I am redirecting the user to the settings page to enable GPS.

[image]

Once I have enabled GPS it in the settings page and rerun the code, I keep getting redirected back to the settings page to enable GPS yet it is already enabled.

Where am I going wrong.

Comment: Maybe it's a permission issue(?) For modern Android versions the permission in the manifest file isn't enough, but you'll need to request it at runtime.

Comment: Markus is correct, you should ask for permissions before checking the location in your code.